# How to get the progress percentage reached in Cygwin using the pipe viewer

Tags: bash, cygwin

`enter code here`I wrote a script to import database from a specified sql file to the specific schema. I use the pipe viewer to see the progress.
when an error happens the load brakes. so i am trying to create a new function to try the load 3 times in case an error happens.(it works fine)
sometime an error happens after the load is completed 100% , so i want to ignore the error in this case.
**Is there a way to know the progress percentage that was reached when the error happened?**

```
try_Load_date_schema(){
    var=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$1").sql;
    count=0;    
    echo $var;
    cddumps;
    echo "starting load ${var}" $2; 
  while true; do
      loadSucceeded=1;
      echo "attempt: "$((count+1));
      dropSchema $2;
      createSchema $2;
      pv $var | mysql --defaults-extra-file=~/localhost.mysql.conf -h 127.0.0.1 -u root --default-character-set=utf8 $2 || loadSucceeded=0;
      if(("$loadSucceeded" == 0));then # i need to check the progress percentage here
          echo "Loading failed"
          if (("$count" == 2));then 
              echo " failed to load db with 3 attempts"
              break;
          else
              echo "try loading again ..."
              ((count++))         
          fi
        else
            echo "load Succeeded"
            break;
        fi
  done
  echo "ending load"; 
}
```

I want to consider the case in [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4v9X.png) as done and do not load again

Comment: It think it would be unwise _to ignore the error_ - after all, it's an error, even if `pv` sent 100 %; this doesn't mean that 100 % were imported.

Comment: I completely understand your point of view. actually only one error can happen after the load is completed 100% and this error can be ignored for now at least.

Answer (score 0):

> **Is there a way to know the progress percentage that was reached when the error happened?**

We can capture the final percentage in a variable and test that for `100%`, so making `loadSucceeded` depend only on that, as you want it, like this:

```
pct=$({ pv $var | mysql --defaults-extra-file=~/localhost.mysql.conf -h 127.0.0.1 -u root --default-character-set=utf8 $2; } |& tee /dev/tty | grep -o '[0-9]\+%' | tail -1)
[ $pct == 100% ] || loadSucceeded=0
```